# Scroll view up when Keyboard hides UiTextField

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I am working on iPad app. In one view we are having 10 textfields. when i view them in the iPad, textfields at the bottom are hidden behind the Keyboard.

I want the textfields to get scrolled up when they are hidden behind the keyboard.

Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 3):

Use a UIScrollView and place your UI controls in the scrollview. In viewDidLoad keep the content offset of scroll view. (in the below code scrollOffset is of type CGPoint.

```
scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
```

In the UITextField delegate set a new content offset for scroll view.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    CGPoint scrollPoint;
    CGRect inputFieldBounds = [textField bounds];
    inputFieldBounds = [textField convertRect:inputFieldBounds toView:scrollView];
    scrollPoint = inputFieldBounds.origin;
    scrollPoint.x = 0;
    scrollPoint.y -= 90; // you can customize this value
    [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];            
}
```

In the textfiedlshouldreturn delegate, reset the content offset of the scrollview.

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField { 
    [scrollView  setContentOffset:scrollOffset animated:YES]; 
    [textField resignFirstResponder]; 
    return YES; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use notifications from the keyboard.
You get UIKeyboardWillShowNotification when keyboard is shown, then you can move or scroll your items, just as you need them.

Best regards
Bernhard

Comment: Thanks for the response Harrer. we are able to do scrolling for the iPhone but not on iPad...Can you post sample code for scrolling the UiTextFeilds.

Comment: What do you mean with "scrolling a UITextField"? You can move the TextField by setting its frame.